# Facebook API using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web, xampp

I am trying to setup my javascript environment using [Facebook Quickstart guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart) watching a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_gLILTRD_k) but I am receiving the error below:

[image]

I have set up my Xampp, as well as the necessary configurations in my .html page inside my Xampp folder.

Below are my code and several screenshots:

```
    <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
</head>

<body>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '240450359740421',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div
  class="fb-like"
  data-share="true"
  data-width="450"
  data-show-faces="true">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**Facebook Developer App setting page:**
[image]

---

**Xampp status:**
[image]

---

**Xampp `index.html` directory:**
[image]

Comment: What happens when you go to http://localhost.com/fbjaspp/index.html?

Comment: It displays the same error of Object not found

Comment: I feel like it's something with xampp. This has nothing to do with the Facebook stuff. Maybe try moving the fbjaspp folder to C:\Xampp\htdocs\ ?

Comment: omg it worked. i changed the URL to http://localhost.com/fbjaspp/index.html and the Like button is displayed. Thank you @JayNCoke. Do reply to this thread so I can tick your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your XAMPP files are in the wrong place.

Move the fbjaspp folder to `C:\xampp\htdocs\`

I'm pretty sure that is where Apache is looking for your HTML files.

I think once that's done you can load http://localhost.com/fbjaspp without the index.html.